# Are those users bots?

Tags: discussion

It's not the first time I noticed that.

Users with the consecutive visit badges but no activity at all on the website

See this user: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/36497/raju?tab=activity

Are those bots ?

Comment: He earned "Fanatic" Badge, its really need lot & lotttt of dedication to earn that badge :-) As he earned 101 reputation, i guess he may be a regular member of other stackexchnage site.

Comment: I think for `Fanatic` badge activity is not necessary.

Comment: Im pretty sure you have to browse questions and be a little bit active to get the badge I'm pretty sure opening the website and not doing anything won't get you the badge

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism I'm pretty sure opening the website will do that.

Comment: @QaisarSatti nope it doesn't, I'm 90% sure you have to browse questions to be considered as active. Simply opening the website would not work

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism  Visit the site each day for 100 consecutive days.

Comment: @QaisarSatti http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66482/consecutive-days-problem-97/66485#66485 'login pages, along with a number of other homepage style pages, don't count as "access" '

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/5832518/raju -- that's his profile on Stack Overflow

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism already opening and visiting counts for fanatic. There is no additional activity needed. i already had 75+ days but "lost" a day, so i had to "restart". Hopefully i won't miss a day in the next 6-7 days :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user has 101 points and a fanatic badge on 143 SE websites (has a few more points on some of them). 
I guess he has a script that opens automatically 2 or 3 pages each day on each website. Or maybe he does it manually? but I doubt it.
I can definitely say he's not a bot.
Here is one of his answers from meta.stackexchange.com
https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277658/224252

Comment: You say, "I guess he has a script that opens automatically 2 or 3 pages", but then say "I can definitely say he's not a bot". What is your definition of a bot? At the very least you suggest he's partly using the account as a bot, correct?

Comment: You can use scripts and still be a person. This could be as simple as an auto-refresh browser plugin.

Comment: He may be a person, but doesn't having a script running for badge considered fraud and thus make him liable to a ban?

Comment: @JulienLachal. It's not moral, but it's not illegal either. I will not ban a user just for this. He is not banned on the other 143 websites either.

Comment: Would he have earned vote-related badge using the same method, would you still not ban him?

Comment: because he earned a badge, no...because of fraudulent points, yes.